# How to add constant value to CSV using batch file?

Tags: text, batch-file, csv

I have a bunch of CSV files that I want to add a constant value to before I merge them so that I know which CSV file each row came from.  I am currently using a simple batch file to merge the CSV files, but I need an identifier to sort the merged file on.

```
copy *.csv importfile.csv
```

so i need to add a constant column of 1's to each row in CSV-A, a constant column of 2's to CSV-B, 3's to CSV-C etc..... before merging the files.

I am sure this is possible, but I have no idea where to start? Can anyone help?

Another option would be.....

```
If any row in column K in CSV-A.csv = "Certain Value" 
change to "1" 
ELSE do nothing
```

Comment: I would just open each of the CSV files in my favourite text editor, and search and replace the CarriageReturn+LineFeeds at the end of each line with the same thing plus an additional `"1",` etc. (plus manually check the first and last lines). That way I'd end up with the new `"1",` at the start of each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "filemask=csv*.csv"
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%c IN (
   'dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\%filemask%" ^|find /n /i ".csv"'
   ) DO (
   SET "firstrow=Y"
   FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%r IN ("%sourcedir%\%%d") DO (
    IF DEFINED firstrow IF %%c==1 ECHO Sourcefile,%%r
    IF NOT DEFINED firstrow ECHO %%c,%%r
    SET "firstrow="
   )
)
)>importfile.csv
```

Set your directory and filemask as appropriate, then
 - build a directory of the target files, `/b` in basic form (filename only) `/a-d` ignore directorynames `/on` in order of name
 - find the `".csv"` (which would occur in each line) `/i` in any case `/n` and number them in `[]`
 - the `"tokens=1*delims=[]"` options assigns the number to %%c and filename to %%d

For each file found,
 - flag that we are processing the first row
 - read each line from the file into %%r
 - if it's the first row in file#1, add "sourcefile," to the header line
 - if it's not the first row, output the file#, prefixed to the row text
 - clear the 'first row' flag

Note that the output filename should not match the filemask chosen. It's fine to produce a .txt file for instance and then rename it.

I've assumed that you need to treat the first row specially. If you don't then simply REM-out the `SET "firstrow=Y"` line with a `REM` keyword (easiest option)

Of course, if you `ECHO %%d,%%r` instead of `ECHO %%c,%%r` then the source filename rather than the serial number of the file will appear (and a few other simplifications could be made - but that's the easiest option if you so choose)